# Elasticsearch URI based search query without source fields

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to execute a URI based query like below. But i don't see any effect of the search parameters i am passing. And also i want to disable _source=false. Can you help me with the query. I am using java to perform the same using Java.net packages. This query return everything no matter what search parameter i pass.

URI: "http://localhost:9200/twitter/twitter/_search?updatedBy=XX&node=YY"

Java Code:

```
   String charset = "UTF-8"; 
            String updatedBy = "XX";
            String node = "YY";

    String query = String.format("updatedBy:%s&nodeId:%s",
            URLEncoder.encode(updatedBy, charset),
            URLEncoder.encode(nodeId, charset));
    System.out.println(searchEsUrl + "?q=" + query);

    URLConnection connection = new URL(searchEsUrl + "?q=" + query).openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

```
String query = String.format("updatedBy:%s+AND+nodeId:%s",
        URLEncoder.encode(updatedBy, charset),
        URLEncoder.encode(nodeId, charset));
URLConnection connection = new URL(searchEsUrl + "?_source=false&q=" + query).openConnection();
```

The issue was that whatever is sent in the `q=` parameter needs to follow the query string query [syntax rules](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax) and two constraints are ANDed using the `AND` operator not `&` like this: `updatedBy:XX AND nodeId:YY`

The URI you want to construct is thus:

```
"http://localhost:9200/twitter/twitter/_search?q=updatedBy:XX AND nodeId:YY"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This works perfectly fine. As you mentioned i was using "&" instead of AND.

Comment: It works fine now. I am even able to disable the source as well as pass size parameter. I have accepted it as an answer.